# electron-builder ignores extraFiles

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I can't seem to get electron-builder to process extraFiles.

```
    "extraFiles": [
  "./build/tools/${platform}/${arch}/wkhtmltopdf"
],
```

I have tried it at root and under "mac", as FileSet and String.  I have purposely made an error in file name to see if I could force an error message, but nope.  No reference to extraFiles when I DEBUG.

Its like it is not even there.

Help?